# Edit specific woocommerce notification message

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On our woocommerce store, we only allow new customers to access the shop after their new account has been manually approved.

However, after successfully registering a new account the user is shown this misleading notification by woocommerce - and I'm not sure where to edit this:

*> Your account was created successfully and a password has been sent to your email address.*

Any ideas on where this message is generated? and how I can change the text

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to edit this message, but I may know a workaround if you want it to make it disappear.

You can try to inspect the element to find out the class and set `display: none` to it in your theme's custom css.

It may buy you time until you find the actual solution.

Comment: Thank you, but I just don't think this will cut it.
The element class name is woocommerce-message - and hiding that may potentially hide other import alerts that do need to be read.